# Temporary Custom Theorem Label

Tags: theorems, newtheorem

I would like to create a temporary custom label for a theorem in Latex, without using `\newtheorem` in the preamble. I want my output to be something like

**Principle of Mathematical Induction**
*Lorem ipsum*

I can achieve this using something similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newtheorem*{induction}{Principle of Mathematical Induction}

\begin{document}

\begin{induction}
A statement about integers is true for all integers greater than or equal to $1$ if 
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item it is true for the integer 1, and
\item whenever it is true for all the integers $1,2,...\,,k$, then it is true for the integer $k+1$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{induction}

\end{document}
```

which produces exactly what I want:

[image: Mathematical Induction]

However, this is clearly not practical at all. I only want to use it once, and it's not convenient that I have it written in the preamble.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Look in the site for `namedtheorem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom environment with an argument that is being passed to the actual theorem environment as a name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\def\partialtheoremname{}
\newtheorem*{partialtheorem}{\partialtheoremname}
\newenvironment{ptheorem}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\partialtheoremname}{#1}%
    \begin{partialtheorem}%
}{%
    \end{partialtheorem}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{ptheorem}{Test}[works like a regular theorem]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{ptheorem}


\begin{ptheorem}{Principle of Mathematical Induction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{ptheorem}


\end{document}
```

[image]